# Converting an address type variable to payable address type throws me error

Tags: solidity, contract-development, address.transfer

I am trying to convert an address to payable address but I'm not able to do it. please find my code below:

```
address a = destinationAddress;
address dest =  address(uint160(a));
dest.transfer(amount);
```

Comment: Why can't you just use `destinationAddress.transfer(amount);`?

Comment: I tried it first but i got same error in which destination address must be of type 'address payable' datatype and now i want my destination address to payable.

Answer (score 1):

You must be using solidity 0.5 or above compiler, just declare destinationAddress as payable : `address payable destinationAddress`, then you can directly use `destinationAddress.transfer(amount);`.

Also check [this](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.0/050-breaking-changes.html) for more breaking changes.